# For which $u$ does the derivative $f'(u,0)$ of $f(x,y)=|xy|^{1/2}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

**Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by setting $f(x,y)=|xy|^{1/2}$**

**(a) For which vectors $u\ne 0$ does $f'(0; u)$ exist? Evaluate it when it
exists.**

**(b) Do $D_1f$ and $D_2f$ exist at $0$?**

**(c) Is $f$ differentiable at $0$?**

**(d) Is $f$ continuous at $0$?**

I have thought a lot about this problem:

For (a), be $u\neq 0, u:=(h,k)$, then $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0+tu)-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(th,tk)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|t^2hk|^{1/2}}{t}=|hk|^{1/2}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|t|}{t}$ and as $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|t|}{t}$ does not exist then necessarily $hk=0$.

For (b), we have that $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0+te_1)-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}0=0$ and so $D_1f(0,0)=0$. Plus $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0+te_2)-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0,t)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}0=0$, then $D_2f(0,0)=0$.

For (c), $f$ is not differentiable in $(0,0)$ since the directional derivative of $f$ in $a$ with respect to the vector $u=(1,1)$ does not exist since $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t,t)-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|t^2|^{1/2}}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|t|}{t}$ and we know that $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|t|}{t}$ does not exist.

For (d), $f$ is continuous in $(0,0)$ because $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}|xy|^{1/2}=0$ and $f(0,0)=0$.

Is this proof of continuity okay? Could anyone help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: Your notation isn't making sense to me. Does $f'$ mean the derivative w.r.t $x$ or $y$?

Comment: And what does $f(0;u)$ mean?

Comment: @Dylan $f'(a,u)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ in $a$ with respect to the vector $u$.

Comment: and $a = (x,y)$?

Comment: I find this super ambigous because we have $f(x,y)$ with the inputs being both scalars, and then $f'$ has inputs of vectors. The notation I'm used to is $\nabla_\boldsymbol{u} f(x,y) = \boldsymbol{u} \cdot \nabla f(x,y) $

Comment: Does $D_1$ and $D_2$ mean the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @Dylan Yes, that is similar, with $D_1f$ I refer to the partial derivative with respect to the first variable of $f$. I am following the same notation from the book "Analysis on manifolds" by Munkres.

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen that before, but I also haven't done a lot of higher level math. Also, if you have $f(x,y)$, why don't they just write $D_xf$ or $f_x$

Comment: @Dylan It's true what you say, I have not used another more standard notation because I do not know it, I'm just learning these subjects, I'm a beginner.